# Load VIM font from file

Tags: fonts, vim

Is there any way to load font from file in Vim? I mean I have for example `~/.vim/somefont.ttf` font file and want to use it as Vim font. Is it possible? Or only system installed fonts are supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot point to `/some/path/somefile.ttf` and ask gvim to use that font, but you can register a font directory locally, for your user.
From the shell, run:

```
$ fc-cache -f ~/.vim
```

(or better yet, `~/.fonts`, since the fonts registered for the user are not specific to vim)